# Trying to get word count using HtmlAgilityPack, but node list is returning as null

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following code that grabs the nodes with text for certain descendants of specific tags/classes, and it was working before, but I haven't ran this program in a couple of months (nobody else has touched it) so I'm wondering why it's throwing an error now. My `nodeList` looks like this:

```
var nodesList = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//article[@class='article-content']//div[@class='article-content-block']//text()[not(parent::script)]")
                .Select(node => node.InnerText).ToList();
```

I look at the web page, and there are multiple paragraph and ul tags that fit that particular `Xpath` query, but `nodesList` is returning:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'
```

The `DocumentNode` has name: `#document`, which I would expect is normal and the `InnerHtml` is showing the entirety of the page's HTML however the `InnerText` is showing `Javascript must be enabled for the correct page display`.  Any ideas as to why it would be throwing null? I don't recall seeing the `Javascript must be enabled for the correct page display` before for the `DocumentNode`'s `InnerText`, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

Comment: View the webpage in your browser with JavaScript disabled, or run curl in your terminal. Do you have the html you're looking for? Is this a website you control?

Comment: It sounds like the webpage content is being loaded dynamically. That's not a problem for your browser, because it executes Javascript automatically, but the .NET web components don't do any of that. You should be able to use your browser's dev tools to determine which request *actually* contains the content you're looking for, and then replicate that request in your code.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, it's my company's site, and the html still loads when I disable javascript. They are static html files being loaded, but I had it working before.

Comment: @SpencerBench We're using DNN, so there is a different url that has the article id/ portal id, etc, but this is a static html page where we strip out all of the dnn content that slows it down, and it's been like that for some time now. But if I use that dnn-specific url, I still get the same error message and null value. I can dig deeper and see if there were any internal changes that would be causing this, I just wanted to check here to see if I was missing something obvious. If you want to write your comment as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the webpage content is being loaded dynamically. That's not a problem for your browser, because it executes Javascript automatically, but the .NET web components don't do any of that. You should be able to use your browser's dev tools to determine which request actually contains the content you're looking for, and then replicate that request in your code.

It could also be that something else about your request isn't playing nice with the server - missing/bad HTTP headers, unexpected TLS version, maybe even firewall stuff - causing it to return a different response.